# How can I make Church numerals more human readable in lisp?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I can define church numerals fairly easy using scheme:

```
> (define f (lambda (x) x))
> (f f) ;0
#<procedure:f>
> (f (f f)) ;1
#<procedure:f>
```

However, this doesn't make it very easy to recognize that `(f f)` is 0 and (f (f f)) is 1.  Is there a way that I can make these numerals more readable?  What would be ideal is this:

```
> (f f)
0
> (f (f f))
1
```

The example is in scheme, but I'll take an answer in any lisp.

Comment: Those aren't church numerals. The way you defined it, `(f f)` is `f`, so `(f (f f))` is `(f f)` is `f`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let's define real church numerals which have the desirable property that `0 != 1`:

```
(define zero (lambda (f x) x))
(define (succ cn) (lambda (f x) (f (cn f x))))
```

So `zero` is the church representation of 0, `(succ zero)` of 1, `(succ (succ zero))` of 2 and so on.

Now since those are just functions, there is no way to tell the repl to display them as numbers, but you can define a function cn-to-int which converts church-numerals to ints which can then be displayed normally:

```
> (define (cn-to-int cn) (cn (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 0))
> (cn-to-int zero)
0
> (cn-to-int (succ zero))
1
> (cn-to-int (succ (succ zero)))
2
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my representation of Church numerals.  :-)